# How to View Submitted Apps for the Ubuntu App Showdown

Tags: application-development

I was wondering how to view the submitted apps for the contest. I am rather interested in what others are doing and so that I can start viewing for the poll. Not to mention I want to try some new apps. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can see what some others are working on at http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown